# jQuery deferred.notify not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I want to use the jQuery Promise Library/API. I wrote tidbit of code to test/learn it, but I'm not getting the expected results.

I paste this code into my javascript console:

```
    window.dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.when(window.dfd.promise()).then(
      function(status) {console.log('resolved, status: ', status);},
      function(status) {console.log('rejected, status: ', status);},
      function(status) {console.log('notified, status: ', status);}
    );
```

At this point, I would expect

```
window.dfd.notify('hello');
```

to trigger the 3rd callback and log to console - but it doesn't.

These both give the expected result:

```
window.dfd.resolve('hello');
window.dfd.reject('hello');
```

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the expected notify result? - and/or what I can do differently to get the expected result?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me James, maybe it is the order you are calling resolve, reject or notify.

Once you resolve or reject a deferred, you can't notify it anymore.

If you try your code as it is and do something like:

```
window.dfd.notify('hello');
window.dfd.resolve('hello');
```

You should see the expected income.

Once you resolve or reject, you don't see notifications anymore so:

```
window.dfd.notify('hello');
window.dfd.resolve('hello');
window.dfd.notify('hello'); //this won't log anything
```

Comment: If I do only the 'notify', without doing a resolve or a reject, I don't get any console log.  I wonder if I'm using the wrong version of jQuery?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 3.1.0.  What version did you use when it worked for you?

Comment: I switched to jQuery 2.2.4 and now it works as expected.  Thanks for the answer to my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used npm to install jquery, it installed jQuery 3.1.0.  I must have been reading the docs for a previous version of jQuery.  It seems they must have changed the Promise API in jQuery3.

After learning that my code worked for klikas I discovered my version issue, installed jQuery 2.2.4, and now it's working great.

Thanks klikas. :)

Comment: Well, notifications are probably deprecated for a reason, so you might want to consider using something else.